# How can I duplicate a TypeScript interface but change the property type in the duplication?

Tags: typescript

I have the following interfaces which are very similar but have different property types:

```
export interface ChannelOverlayStyles {
    bigChannelLogoWrapper: ViewStyle;
    bigPackshotChannelLogo: ViewStyle;
    channelLogo: ViewStyle;
    channelPackshotGradient: ViewStyle;
    smallChannelLogoWrapper: ViewStyle;
    portraitLogo: ViewStyle;
    landscapeLogo: ViewStyle;
}

 export interface ChannelOverlayStylesWeb {
    bigChannelLogoWrapper: ViewStyleWeb;
    bigPackshotChannelLogo: ViewStyleWeb;
    channelLogo: ViewStyleWeb;
    smallChannelLogoWrapper: ViewStyleWeb;
    portraitLogo: ViewStyleWeb;
    landscapeLogo: ViewStyleWeb;
 }
```

Is there away I can avoid duplicating these by creating a type that duplicates the first interface but replaces the property type automatically?

Comment: What did you try and why didn't it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can abstract the common types to a base interface that is generic over the field type. While limiting the generic field type to only `ViewStyleWeb | ViewStyle`

```
export interface ChannelOverlayBase<View extends ViewStyleWeb | ViewStyle> {
    bigChannelLogoWrapper: View;
    bigPackshotChannelLogo: View;
    channelLogo: View;
    smallChannelLogoWrapper: View;
    portraitLogo: View;
    landscapeLogo: View;
 }

export type ChannelOverlayStyles = ChannelOverlayBase<ViewStyle> & {channelPackshotGradient: ViewStyle}

export type ChannelOverlayStylesWeb = ChannelOverlayBase<ViewStyleWeb>;
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?pretty=true#code/PTAEEEGdIVwWwKYFgBQAXAngBwaAagJYIDuAypgDYIDqCARqALygBKCAxgPYBOAJgDyQ03AgDsA5gBpQMUQGtRnYqIB8qTDnxEylXMzZc+g4WKkz5i5SoDaAXVSpQCAB5YeaUGLQJuAMwCG7LgAwgAW-qKiCBQA8gBuPhT+GABC-pAI-IQkTs7eoryQWiTkGFS0DAA+xTplCCqgAN6OoK10BOJhEVEUADKc4pzU3P5YONwAXDUA3C1tHQAKgXKQoZxoXZHR-YNT2cSzKK2t7OFbfQOce9qHx6CQcP4UFJs9O0MjYz7XJLfHbtxhP4CGh3j8DnNQEkCpB2KMEGCZo4AL4OFAuAEeDQhM49eKJZKlKhFZivaL47hJVLpTL7In1UAAMiap260SW7BWazQAHERrwiKI0OD6dNUShHBj3KBsaAybEEpTCbpIBUmHLceTFVS0hkstp6RUVNMgA)